# Raising multiple exceptions from threads in Python

Tags: python, exception

tl;dr I spawn 3 threads, each thread throws an exception, most pythonic way to raise all 3 exceptions?

Below is a code example that is similar to what I am doing.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def fail_func(host):
    raise Exception('{} FAILED!!!'.format(host))

hosts = ['172.1.1.1', '172.1.1.2', '172.1.1.3']
pool = ThreadPool(processes=5)
workers = [pool.apply_async(fail_func(host)) for host in hosts]
# join and close thread pool
pool.join(); pool.close()
# get the exceptions
[worker.get() for worker in workers if not worker.successful()]
```

What it ends up doing is just failing on the 1st host with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    workers = [pool.apply_async(fail_func(host)) for host in hosts]
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 4, in fail_func
    raise Exception('{} FAILED!!!'.format(host))
Exception: 172.1.1.1 FAILED!!!
```

But what I want it to do is raise multiple exceptions for each thread that failed, like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    workers = [pool.apply_async(fail_func(host)) for host in hosts]
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 4, in fail_func
    raise Exception('{} FAILED!!!'.format(host))
Exception: 172.1.1.1 FAILED!!!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    workers = [pool.apply_async(fail_func(host)) for host in hosts]
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 4, in fail_func
    raise Exception('{} FAILED!!!'.format(host))
Exception: 172.1.1.2 FAILED!!!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 8, in <module>
    workers = [pool.apply_async(fail_func(host)) for host in hosts]
  File "thread_exception_example.py", line 4, in fail_func
    raise Exception('{} FAILED!!!'.format(host))
Exception: 172.1.1.3 FAILED!!!
```

is there any pythonic way of doing this? or do I need to wrap everything in a try/except, collect all the messages, then re-raise a single Exception?

Comment: As a side note, it's a little confusing to call your results objects `worker`. Normally, that word refers to the subprocesses in the pool.

Comment: As another side note, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` is an undocumented feature, while `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is documented and should give you what you want. I personally think that in this case, the much clearer name `ThreadPool` vs. `dummy.Pool` outweighs that, but it's worth knowing the choice for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "raise multiple exceptions". In a given exception context, there is either an exception, or not.

So yes, you will have to create a wrapper exception that holds all of the exceptions, and raise that. But you've almost got all the code you need:

```
def get_exception():
    try:
        worker.get()
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Now, instead of:

```
[worker.get() for worker in workers if not worker.successful()]
```

… you can just do:

```
[get_exception(worker.get) for worker in workers if not worker.successful()]
```

And that's a list of exceptions.

---

Personally, I've always thought `AsyncResult` should have an `exception` method, similar to the one in [`concurrent.futures.Future`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.exception). But then I would have used `futures` here in the first place (installing the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) if I were forced to use Python 2.x).